# Rails 4 - link_to not working in firefox or IE (also bootstrap design not showing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails app that has links included in bootstrap buttons.

```
<td>
<button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>&nbsp;
<%= link_to 'Details', user_story %>
</button>
</td>
```

The HTML shows up properly, and the link is assigned correctly in the anchor tags:

```
<td><button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>&nbsp;<a href="/user_stories/1">Details</a>
</button>
</td>
```

It works in chrome but not in Firefox or IE. However when I remove the bootstrap styling, the link_to function does work...
How can I keep bootstrap styling on my pages and keep cross browser compatibility?  Or is there a way to force rails to assign the anchor tags around the button?
for example: `<td><a href="/user_stories/1"><button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>&nbsp;Details</button></a></td>`
**Update:**
Now in firefox but *not in IE* it works using:

```
<% link_to user_story do %>
    <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>&nbsp;Details</button>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not valid HTML to have a link inside of a button. It is easy to make links look like buttons, though. Try something like:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to user_story, class: 'btn btn-default' do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Details 
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, in both firefox and IE. Thank you good sir!

Comment: This solution does not even appear on Firefox 47.0 (OSX) or Safari. However, the update by the OP is working on Firefox. I don't have IE so i cannot confirm.